# PySide2 QImage Искажается картинка при сохранении в JPG

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qimage

Я делаю небольшой редактор скриншотов, поэтому мне нужно отредактировать картинку и потом ее сохранить без потери качества, но когда я сохраняю ее, то картинка искажается. Как этого избежать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот упрощенный пример кода:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QColor, QPen, QPainter
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

app = QApplication([])

# Загружаем картинку
image = QImage("input.jpg")

# Редактируем картинку
painter = QPainter(image)
pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.red), 2)
painter.setPen(pen)
painter.drawRect(10, 10, 20, 20)

# Сохраняем отредактированную картинку
image.save("output.jpg")

app.exec_()
```

Comment: У функции `save`, должен быть параметр `quality`, настройте его.

Comment: JPEG - в принципе формат со сжатием с потерей информации, при множественном пересохранении качество ухудшается, даже если quality на максимум выставлять. Чтобы качество не ухудшалось, можно использовать например PNG.

Comment: `image.save("output.png")`